# Deleting Entities in NDB last child is always being deleted

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

I have models similar to the example found on the documentation for Python GAE (Greeting and Author). I have a problem when it comes to deletion because it is always the last child that is being deleted and not the entity that I was targeting.

```
class Delete(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def post(self):
         greeting_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('for_deletion')) #it's the key's urlsafe that is being passed here
         greeting_key.delete()
         self.redirect('/events')
```

Here is a code snippet of what generates the request:

```
               self.response.write('''<br><br><form action="/delete" method="post">        
                   <input type="hidden" name="for_deletion" value="%s">
                   <input type="submit" value="Delete Most Recent Info"><br><br>
               <form>
               ''' % post.key.urlsafe())
```

Comment: Without getting a look at what your `for_deletion` param contents are, this will be hard for us to debug.
What does the code look like that generates this request?

Comment: @Josh It's actually a hidden input <input type="hidden" name="for_deletion" value="%s">. The value is the key.urlsafe. I can show you the entire code in bit bucket.

Comment: I did further debugging, and I have come into the conclusion that there is no problem with the ndb delete function but on the value being returned by self.request.get('for_deletion') in the html page that generates the request. I will update this as soon as I am done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arised from the fact that I have a lot of hidden inputs with the name="for_deletion". The server script chooses that last in queue that's why I get to have the last child deleted.

I have modified that html page that generates the request in a sense that I used javascript to ask the user if he/she wants to delete the data and then I would go on about sending a form with a hidden input named "for_deletion". In that way I will ensure that there is only one html element name="for_deletion".

Here is a code snippet of the js file:

```
         document.body.innerHTML += '<form id="dynForm" action="/delete" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="for_deletion" value=' + urlsafe + '></form>';
         document.getElementById("dynForm").submit();
```